# how to set PreparedStatement place holders for Equi join?

Tags: oracle, prepared-statement

i have a query in that i need to pass values for the `equi join` 
 i have tried below

```
package com.iseva.Servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import Connectionfactory.ConnectionFactory;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class GetDetailsFROutWard
 */
@WebServlet("/GetDetailsFROutWard")
public class GetDetailsFROutWard extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Connection cn=null;
    public void init()
    {
        cn=ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
        System.out.println("connection up");
    }
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String ref=request.getParameter("t2");
    System.out.println();
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps=cn.prepareStatement("select PAYMENT_DETAILS.CUSTOMER_NAME,PAYMENT_DETAILS.MOBILE_NUMBER_1,customer_data.SHOP_CITY from PAYMENT_DETAILS ,customer_data where PAYMENT_DETAILS.iseve_ref_num=?=customer_data.iseve_ref_num=?");
        ps.setString(1, ref);
        ps.setString(2, ref);
        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()) 
        {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

}
```

but gives `Exception`

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:440)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:837)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:445)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:523)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:863)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1153)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1275)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3576)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3620)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1491)
    at com.iseva.Servlet.GetDetailsFROutWard.doGet(GetDetailsFROutWard.java:37)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1104)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1519)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1475)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

how to put place `holders` for joins in `PreparedStatement`

```
PAYMENT_DETAILS.num=customer_data.num
```

there i want to put place `holders and pass values` as

```
ps.setString(1, ref);
ps.setString(2, ref);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I need to write and run your piece of Sql statement to understand the exception clearly, but by observation I could see that in your statement "***where PAYMENT_DETAILS.iseve_ref_num=?=customer_data.iseve_ref_num=?*** "

Can you just put `'And'` between the 2 where clauses and try again please? like:

```
"where PAYMENT_DETAILS.iseve_ref_num=? And customer_data.iseve_ref_num=?"
```

I think the query needs to be modified. One more thing you can do is to run the Sql statement in any sql tool like *Sqldeveloper* or else to be confirmed about such exceptions.

Comment: THANK YOU i did it just before , thank you for the response